# Problem with lineHeight in Text Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have some problem with lineHeight in Text wiget.
Let me show what i mean on example.
I have two columns with two types Text widgets. First have lineHeight eaqual 2.em, second 0.em.

```
Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Column {
        repeat(10) {
            Text(
                text = "Test1-$it",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                    lineHeight = 2.em,
                    lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                        alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
                        trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
                    )
                ),
            )
        }
    }
    Column {
        repeat(10) {
            Text(
                text = "Test2-$it",
                style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
                    TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                        lineHeight = 0.em,
                        lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                            alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
                            trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
                        )
                    ),
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Why Text with smaller lineHeight have bigger paddings?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what's happening in this scenario is that when providing `0.em` as line height, it'll cause Compose to use the default line size height which is bigger than `2.em`. Try using `1.em` for Test2 instead of `0.em` and see the results.